# manga about boy who is killed and revived in modern world

Tags: story-identification, manga

IIRC it's set in the modern world. The boy is killed and brought back to life by a girl. The girl (I think) dies in his place instead and everyone forgets her. In order to bring her back he has to find the killer and touch their head with his hand? And then I think the first person he finds is a girl who killed him by pushing him in a train or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any characters or places?

Comment: Was this in full colour and what colour was the boy and girl's hair? Also, what was the precise nature of the boy's revival? Was time reversed to a point before his death? Or was the corpse itself restored to life?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[Shichiha Gojuuroku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120804)*, aka *7x8=56*

> The story follows a teenage boy who wants to become famous with girls. One day, he finds a girl drowning in the river. Ever since then, a strange relationship started!

The first chapter has the protagonist, Funobori Gorou, going about his daily life. He finds a girl, Fujimiya Shichiha, nearly drowning and saves her. He nearly kisses her while attempting to do CPR, and she warns him that if he had kissed her, he "wouldn't get off easy". Later that day he finds her about to fall off a cliff, saves her again, and accidentally kisses her while pulling her back over the fence.

Shortly after he is abruptly kicked in front of a train as it passes by, killing him.

[image: Kicked in front of train]

He witnesses his own funeral as a ghost, but snaps back to his mangled body. The girl is there and "saves" him by taking his place, restoring his body but leaving her own mangled body in its place. She asks him to find the culprit.

He's restored to life by this action, but at this point has not gone back in time. He goes to school the next day and sees the girl's death mentioned in the newspaper, including the expected date.

He gets a letter to return to the railroad crossing where he died, written by the girl. He returns there and meets a woman he talked to earlier. After some short dialog, she stabs him in the back - she was the murderer who kicked him in front of the train. Remembering the words to "find the culprit", he touches her forehead. This results in time rewinding to the previous day, restoring himself and Shichiha back to life. The culprit is forcibly moved in front of the train, as someone has to die, and then time returns back to the current day.