# Manga where male MC dies in train accident, but the female MC revives him using her life so he may learn the cause of his death

Tags: story-identification, manga

A high-school boy dies in a train accident (later revealed to be murder), who is reset/revived about a week prior to his death by a girl in his class. She was able to do this by giving up her own life force/existence through an ability passed down through each generation of her family.

They use his second chance and her ability to learn the cause of his death.
I think the male main character had blonde/dyed hair (I don't remember too well), but the female main character has red-eyes and long dark-blue hair. The top of her head had a spiky cowlick resembling a Rooster.

Comment: Likely the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266822 . No answers, but it may have some additional details.

Comment: Do you remember if this was in black&white or full color? About what year did you read this?

Comment: It had colored covers but was mostly black&white, this was around 2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely *[Shichiha Gojuuroku](https://myanimelist.net/manga/120804)*, aka *7x8=56*

> The story follows a teenage boy who wants to become famous with girls. One day, he finds a girl drowning in the river. Ever since then, a strange relationship started!

[image: Cover image]

Cover image shows the blonde male main character and black-haired female main character. She does have a prominent cowlick.

The first chapter has the protagonist, Funobori Gorou, going about his daily life. He finds a girl, Fujimiya Shichiha, nearly drowning and saves her. He nearly kisses her while attempting to do CPR, and she warns him that if he had kissed her, he "wouldn't get off easy". Later that day he finds her about to fall off a cliff, saves her again, and accidentally kisses her while pulling her back over the fence.

Shortly after he is abruptly kicked in front of a train as it passes by, killing him.

[image: Kicked in front of train]

He witnesses his own funeral as a ghost, but snaps back to his mangled body. The girl is there and "saves" him by taking his place, restoring his body but leaving her own mangled body in its place. She asks him to find the culprit.

He's restored to life by this action, but at this point has not gone back in time. He goes to school the next day and sees the girl's death mentioned in the newspaper, including the expected date.

He gets a letter to return to the railroad crossing where he died, written by the girl. He returns there and meets a woman he talked to earlier. After some short dialog, she stabs him in the back - she was the murderer who kicked him in front of the train. Remembering the words to "find the culprit", he touches her forehead. This results in time rewinding to the previous day, restoring himself and Shichiha back to life. The culprit is forcibly moved in front of the train, as someone has to die, and then time returns back to the current day.